# Tracking changes and different iterations of a configuration file

Tags: php, deployment

I have a number of different versions of a php application, configuration file. Currently the conf folder is being ignored by git, but I'd like to track the changes to config.ini separately, and also label where each version of the config.ini should be. We are not using any specific deployment tools, and though ive looked at capistrano, we are not ready to use it. Also, I looked into using gist or a subrepo. But unsure how to track the deployments. Each config file is ignored, so i'd like to track versions and deployment history. So, when deploying to production I can track changes, and prevent conflicts that introduce bugs.

This is a rough outline of what I mean.

```
Master Branch -> Production Config
Development Branch -> Development Config
Developer Jacks Local Dev, Branch A -> Config A
Developer Jacks Local Dev, Branch B -> Config B
Developer Jill Local Dev, Branch A -> Config A
Developer Jill Local Dev, Branch B -> Config B
```

So if Jack merges Branch A to master branch, and deploys code to production, the config file changes are deployed safely.

**UPDATE:** Been playing with git submodules a little today, and having difficulties push code back up to a remote repo. I'll stick with it, but its not looking good so far.

Comment: This sounds like standard features of just about any CVS. Im unclear about what you feel you need is different?

Comment: ok, maybe im explaining it wrongly. All config files are added to gitignore file, so changes are not being tracked. Whenever a change needs to be made to production configuration file, we have to do it directly on the server.

Comment: I thought about creating a git sobmodule for the production config file, which is doable. But we have at least 5 different itteration of a config file, that we are sharing back and forward with each other when testing new features, as well as the production config file.

Comment: the config file has maybe 1,000 lines, so tracking changes to it, is very difficult.

Comment: Have you looked into forking your configs? this way they would be come fully maintainable. You should be able to clone and maintain upstreams to link everything without issues.

You could go an expanded method, where each developer has their own fork. This way, all configs are separated and can be issues with an origin pull request, and tracked each step of the way.

Comment: ok, so create a submodule containing the config file and create a fork for each iteration ie config_production, config_feature1, config_feature2. So when user wants a specific iteration, clone that submodule, make changes and merge upstream.